# Am I using structures and protocols correctly within Swift?

Tags: swift

POI stands for points of interest in the following code.

I am trying to distinguish between routes that have points of interest on them. A route can be either an east/west bound route or a north/south bound route.

I have a method that determines whether the route is east/west bound or north/south bound:

`func getRouteDirection() -> DirectionForRoute{...}`

Based on the direction determined within this method, the method constructs a `DirectionForRoute` object to return. This object has the following definition:

```
protocol Couplable{}

struct DirectionForRoute{

    var routeDirection: String
    var POIs: Couplable

    init(routeDirection: String, POIs: Couplable) {
        self.routeDirection = routeDirection
        self.POIs  = POIs
    }

}
```

The `routeDirection` variable is self-explanatory it basically takes one of two possible values either `"EAST/WEST"` or `"NORTH/SOUTH"`.

The `POIs` variable however, is a bit more complex. Based on the route's direction I want the `POIs` variable to be assigned one of two possible structures:

```
struct EastWestBoundPOIs: Couplable {
    var eastBoundPOIs: [POI]
    var westBoundPOIs: [POI]

    init(eastBoundPOIs: [POI], westBoundPOIs: [POI]) {
        self.eastBoundPOIs = eastBoundPOIs
        self.westBoundPOIs = westBoundPOIs
    }
}

struct NorthSouthBoundPOIs: Couplable {
    var northBoundPOIs: [POI]
    var southBoundPOIs: [POI]

    init(northBoundStops: [POI], southBoundStops: [POI]) {
        self.northBoundPOIs = northBoundPOIs
        self.southBoundPOIs = southBoundPOIs
    }
}
```

When the `getRouteDirection()` method return a value of type `DirectionForRoute` I cannot access the internal variables of the last two structures assigned to the `POIs` variable because it is of type `Couplable`.

My question is, am I using structures correctly to achieve what I am looking for to do? Is there a better way to do this?

P.S. I want to try to avoid casting if that is possible.

Comment: Is this really your code? The line `self.routeDirection = routeDirection` makes no sense, as there is no incoming parameter called `routeDirection`. On my machine, that's a compilation error: "error: assigning a property to itself".

Comment: @matt Probably just a typo. `routeBound` for `routeDirection` mixup.

Comment: It was a typo. I fixed it. @matt

Comment: @nathan Certainly it's a typo, but it is the OP's job to show meaningful code.

Comment: Cool. — I have to admit I have no idea what you're trying to do. The notion that you need a whole struct just to say whether a route is east-west or north-south seems nutty to me, and I don't understand how and why a direction can have POIs. And I don't at all see why you need two kinds of POIs. Your types should be like real-world things. We don't think that way in real life. In real life, a route has a direction and it also has POIs. Done. What's wrong with that?

Comment: If a POI can be northbound or southbound, that is a feature _of the POI_, not a collection you put the POI _into_.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't write something much simpler and closer to our human intuitions:

```
enum Direction {
    case northSouth
    case eastWest
}

enum Side {
    case left
    case right
}

struct POI {
    let side : Side
}

struct Route {
    let pois : [POI]
    let direction : Direction
}
```

You now only have to make up a convention for what "left" and "right" mean. Let's say they are reckoned in terms of the first direction in a Direction's name. Now it is trivial to calculate, given a Route, which POIs are on the side of the road we're traveling.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea. It's simpler than your solution, but it doesn't have as nice naming conventions. However, it might give you some ideas and allow you to refactor to fit your exact needs.

First, instead of a `String` representing the direction, use an `enum`.

```
enum Direction {
    case northSouth
    case eastWest
}
```

Next, your `DirectionForRoute` would make more sense to be named just `Route`, which has a direction and some points of interest.

```
struct Route {
    var direction: Direction
    var northOrEastPOIs: [POI]
    var southOrWestPOIs: [POI]
}
```